# How to get a PDO Fetch( ) to return as string

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

How can I get a PDO to return the data as a string not an array? I am not sure this is possible so if not is there a way to convert the array to a string after it has been processed?

My code which is returning the string is:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
```

I have tried different fetch types such as `FETCH_CLASS` `FETCH_OBJ`

Comment: Do you just want just 1 specific column or the entire row as a string?

Comment: `fetch` always returns a *row*. What's so hard about picking the field from it that you want?

Comment: You could use `list()`, but that's a really risky if the result set varies.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
echo $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Or:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result[0];
```

Comment: i think you mean `echo $stmt->fetchColumn();`

Comment: Perfect. Using echo $stmt->fetchColumn(1); Will let me pick the column I wish to display. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if it answered your question, then. Happy to help!

Comment: One quick question. Using echo $stmt->fetchColumn(); will fetch a column of my choice, how do i get it to fetch all the 1st columns?

Comment: `stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, $columnId)`

Comment: Excelent approach when using a mysql procedure. You just need to add `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();`  at the end of it.

Comment: This doesn't appear to resolve the "return as string" part of this question.  If the column you are fetching is an int, you will get an int.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $statement->fetchColumn();
```

This work for me, the only thing I noticed here is that fetchColumn() always refer to first column on your table. You need to adjust / re-position the only column needed to the first-column on your table or make an Sql query i.e "SELECT" query to get the only column needed. Thanks